# listbox scrolling

Tags: winforms, listbox

I want to disable scrolling ( not hide the scroll bar but disallow scrolling altogether) when the user selects certain items in my listbox
if the user moves to a differnet item ( the criterai are not important ) then I want to re-enable scrolling
How can I do this in .NET 2.0

Comment: Would toggling .Enabled work for your situation?

Answer (score 0):

Override CreateParams property of ListBox class.

```
public class My : ListBox
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style &= ~0x00200000; // VScroll
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

Add following code to test,

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            My c = new My();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
               c.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }
            this.Controls.Add(c);
        }
```

Comment: this worls on XP but not on Vista
any idea why